# Generate template for table

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

I've object which is coming from postgres DB and I want to expose it in the UI with nice table, there is something that can help me to generate this table quickly ? I use yeoman in the past but when you generate some template it generate a lot of things for you (which I want to avoid) is there is some lightweight tool which can help me to do it?

I need to display and add new records in the table.

This is my sample table content

```
  { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Foo' },
  { firstname: 'Jenny', lastname: 'Bar' },
  { firstname: 'Dan', lastname: 'Bazz' },
```

Comment: Use some view engine like handlebars.js, mustache, jade(pug), ejs, swig, dust, and many more.

Comment: @Molda - Thanks but how can I use it with bootstrap or some nice Ui...,is there is something which I can use by generation tool ?

Comment: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/handlebars.md does this help?

Comment: @Molda - Thanks,this can help but  did you used it? can you give example how to use it for generating table ,simple table will be very helpful. (my object is very simple first name ,last name)

Comment: Check the documentation on handlebarsjs.com `<table>{{#list people}}<tr><td>{{firstName}}</td> <td>{{lastName}}</td></tr>{{/list}}`

Comment: @Molda it will be great if as an answer you can add how I map my object to  it 2. if there is easy option to apply some nice ui to this table. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Molda - I've update the question with the sample table, thank you!